# I am getting no lighting or anything else in my render

Tags: interface

[image]

So I opened blender, made new file and pressed a F12. I changed nothing and I get this as output. Is this output what I should get? I couldn't find anyone that got this result. What should I try to fix my issue? I am using amd gpu.

Comment: probably a problem with the latest AMD driver, try the previous one or in the the Properties panel > Render > Performance, try High Quality Normals

Answer (score 1):

Issue is solved by moonboots and his suggestion to Properties panel > Render > Performance, try High Quality Normals.